# How to get unique data between 2 dates with a date range?

Tags: mysql

I've got a query where I am trying to find the unique items that were sold between 2 dates, for example `01/01/2022` and `01/09/2022` (DD/MM/YYYY). I want to find the unique items which were sold between 30 day intervals.

The table from which I am trying to pull this data has the following columns.

1. Date
2. Item_Number

This is my query.

```
SELECT Date-30 as start_range, 
       Date as end range, 
       count(distinct unique_items) as Items 
From tableT1
WHERE date between 01012022 and 01092022
GROUP BY date-30, date
```

The data that is returned is for a particular day and doesn't give the output for the date range (date-30 and date).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/

Comment: Start by storing dates in `DATE` columns with data like "2022-01-01".  Don't use plain arithmetic for dates; use `INTERVAL` arithmetic.